# RichTextBox - Remove Last Character(s) Without Removing Formatting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, colors, formatting, richtextbox

### Goal

I'm trying to remove the last comma & space from my RichTextBox.

### Current Result

Here is the result of my RichTextBox. It contains various different categories which are split in different colors to make it easier for the user to read.

[image: RichTextbox With Formatting]

But, as you can see: a comma and a space (space isn't visible) are after the *Solenoid Valve*

---

### Attempt To Solve The Problem

I used the following code to trim the last comma and last space in my RichTextBox.

```
If rtbSummary.Text.Substring(rtbSummary.TextLength - 2, 2).Contains(", ") Then
    rtbSummary.Text = rtbSummary.Text.Remove(rtbSummary.TextLength - 2, 2)
End If
```

Keep in mind, this works. The only issue with this is I lose my formatting:

[image: RichTextBox Lost Formatting]

---

So how can I go about removing the last comma and space from a RichTextBox without affecting the color format?

The reason a comma and space are present in my RichTextBox is because of the way I loop around my list of objects to populate the RichTextbox. If I was to verify if there were other items in order to place a comma, I would be looping through a lot of stuff. I figured just a trim would be less resource consuming than nested loops.

Comment: The RichTextBox as two ways to get content .Text and .RichText. If you capture the .richText you can look at it to see how to get to the characters you need to delete.

Comment: @rheitzman Ahh I didn't know there was a RichText ... Thanks, I'll be sure to look into it!

Comment: Error on my part: .Text and .Rtf not .Text and .RichText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the Text property removes all of the formatting of the existing text.  Try using the Selection methods to change it:

```
Dim lastComma As Integer = rtb.Text.LastIndexOf(",")
If lastComma > -1 Then
  rtb.Select(lastComma, rtb.Text.Length - lastComma)
  rtb.SelectedText = String.Empty
End If
```

Comment: Turns out if the text you replace .Text with is proper RTF things work fine. We store RTF in a varchar(max) field in SQL Server and insert it via .Rtf and it works. In the OP the mistake was to remove some of the RTF command instead of the desired characters. (I made a mistake earlier, the RichText property is .Rtf not .RichText)

Answer (score 1):

*Refering to LarsTech's advice.*

Keep in mind that if you have **Readonly** enabled then you'll have to disable it temporarily during the text removal. Otherwise it will ignore your effort (*rtb.SelectedText = String.Empty*) and keep the text selected.